# webjar not loading in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, webjars

None of `js` or `css` is loading from webjar in spring boot application. I added the required dependencies and I am able to see the jars.

```
<script src="webjars/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

This is giving 404 error, I also added below configuration to resolve this still no use.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc

        public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

            public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.enable();
            }

            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
                registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
            }


        /*  *//**
           * 
           * @return ViewResolver
           */
            @Bean
            public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
                InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
                resolver.setPrefix("/");
                resolver.setSuffix(".html");
                return resolver;
            }
```

My POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__forms</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__http</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__platform-browser</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__platform-browser-dynamic</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__router</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-rc.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__router-deprecated</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__upgrade</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>systemjs</artifactId>
            <version>0.19.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-js</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflect-metadata</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjs</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-beta.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>zone.js</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular2-in-memory-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Please help

Comment: Can you show your WebJar dependencies (Maven/Gradle)? Normally WebJars have a version number in their path, unless you have the **webjars-locator** on your classpath which makes them version agnostic. Anyhow, you shouldn't have to configure any resource handler.

Comment: I am using maven, webjar-locator is in the spring boot starter pack so I am not providing the version.

Comment: I am not using thymeleaf I am using html files and keeping them in web app folder. Will that be a problem

Comment: It's very unclear what you're saying right now. Did you add **webjars-locator** to your Maven/Gradle descriptor or not? Please provide your WebJar dependencies like I asked before, right now there's no way to tell whether or not you included the right dependencies.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    <version>${webjars-locator.version}</version>
   </dependency> This is present in the spring boot in built so I dont have to explicit ad it in my POM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're referencing files called **webjars/core-js/client/shim.min.js**, however, this is not the correct path to the file except when you're using **webjars-locator** which provides version agnostic paths according to [their documentation](http://www.webjars.org/documentation#springboot):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the comments you mentioned that Spring boot adds this dependency by itself, but this is not true. Spring boot does have the dependency listed, but only in the [`<dependencyManagement>` section](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L2357-L2361), which is not the same as adding a dependency.

Spring Web MVC also lists it as a dependency, but as an [**optional** dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/build.gradle#L877), which means you have to explicitly add it.

Comment: There is somehow mentioned: webjars-locator-core in some guides to spring, but that is wrong!